# AWS resource type - AWS::ECS::Cluster & AWS::ECS::Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

[Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-service.html) does not talk the exact purpose of these two resource types, except its usage.

---

With an example [code](https://gist.github.com/anupam-ncsu/ef04bd05721611a6477bd3332c686323#file-jenkinsmasterservice-yaml-L28) of 
 master Jenkins, shown below:

master jenkins cluster(`Cluster: !Ref Cluster`) is being used by `AWS::ECS::Service` resource type, to schedule tasks on `!Ref Cluster` as shown below:

```
ServicesJenkinsMaster: 
        Type: AWS::ECS::Service
        Properties: 
            Cluster: !Ref Cluster
            DesiredCount: !Ref DesiredMasterCount
            DeploymentConfiguration:
              MaximumPercent: 100
              MinimumHealthyPercent: 50            
            PlacementConstraints: 
                - Type: distinctInstance 
            TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskDefinition
```

**where as** the jenkins slave cluster(`ECSCluster`) in below [code](https://gist.github.com/anupam-ncsu/3b46ab133425e3077d4e576758c079de#file-jenkinsslavecluster-yaml-L54), is not being used by `AWS::ECS::Service` resource type

```
ECSCluster:
        Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
        Properties:
            ClusterName: !Sub ANUPAM_${EnvironmentName}_Jenkins_Slave
```

---

I know that `AWS::ECS::Service` is used to schedule tasks on a given cluster(`Cluster` property). `DesiredCount:n` property tells that `n` instances of those tasks need to be maintained at any point of time, where each task is of type `AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition`.

But am unclear about not using slave cluster `ECSCluster` with `AWS::ECS::Service` resource type

[Here](https://miro.medium.com/max/980/0*LOcTEgLcWA2pBLlT.png) is a jenkins architecture created with these cloudformation scripts.

---

In the above scenario, Why slave jenkins cluster(`ECSCluster`) is not being used by `AWS::ECS::Service` type, unlike master Jenkins cluster?

When do we use `Cluster` property with `AWS::ECS::Service` type?

Does [ECS 
 jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Amazon+EC2+Container+Service+Plugin) setting take care of the functionality of  `AWS::ECS::Service` type using `ECSCluster`. Because tasks need to be scheduled on slave cluster(`ECSCluster`) with specific `DesiredCount`.

Comment: The slave task is managed by Jenkin ECS plugin. More information can be found  https://github.com/jenkinsci/amazon-ecs-plugin and https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Amazon+EC2+Container+Service+Plugin

Comment: @Apolozeus yes I added ECS plugin in my query. But, when you say ECS plugin manage, what does that mean? Does it register the `ECSCluster` with ECS service? Internally

Comment: Yes, it does. The plugin will make sure that if there is any jobs pending to be executed, it will spin up the task for the same. This is quite common for any CI tool in term of cost saving.

Comment: @Apolozeus Don't we have such option to create cluster(of type `AWS::ECS::Cluster`) of 3 EC2 instances running, irrespective of the task load they carry. Because `DesiredCount` property says: "The number of instantiations of the **specified task definition** (not EC2 instances) to place and keep running on your cluster."

Comment: Not sure if I understand your point correctly. In ECS, we have cluster params like (# min/max EC2 instances), and also auto scaling policy to scale down/up the cluster in term of ec2 instances (we can see the same in slave CF). The task configuration is another thing, provided that we have enough resource in your EC2 instances, the task can go up and down. In case that there is no space in EC2 (cpu, memory, etc), the task placement will be failed with error (unable to place task). There is new ECS feature to avoid this issue, but we leave it for now.

Comment: @Apolozeus can you give me documentation  reference to property min/max for EC2 instances in a cluster? I would like to read it.

Comment: it's not directly under `Cluster`, but you can refer to this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/d eveloperguide/launch_container_instance.html for the LaunchConfiguration, then then `AutoScalingGroup` which links to LaunchConfiguration. I personally refer to official aws example for reference, here is one https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/blob/master/aws/services/ECS/EC2LaunchType/clusters/public-vpc.yml

Comment: @Apolozeus ya this property with autoscaling, I know. So, without autoscaling configuration, any `AWS::ECS::Cluster` cannot maintain minimum number of EC2 instances? So, what is `AWS::ECS::Cluster` ensuring about your EC2 instances? When you configure ECS.config file to to join a cluster...`"echo ECS_CLUSTER=", { "Ref": "EcsCluster" }, " >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config\n"`

Comment: I see `AWS::ECS::Cluster` is kind of logical resource only. The underlying instance could be fargate or ec2. If it's ec2, it `must` be configured with auto scaling group and lauch configuration. In case of fargate, AWS will manage underlying server.